# Python: Two way replacement in a string.

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to replace all the single quotes with double quotes and vice versa. So for example change this string `"1": " 'me' and 'you'"` to `'1': '"me" and "you"'`, how can I do that? if i do `mystering.replace('"', "'")` then will be converted to ' and then if I do the reverse of it `mystering.replace( "'", '"')`, all will be converted to ".

Comment: `str.translate`

Comment: I believe you must use use `str.translate`. `.replace.replace` will still have his existing issue I believe. The output would just be: 
    `"1": " "me" and "you""`

Comment: Correct. I don't understand why you and doing `'""'`? Why isn't it `'"'`?

Comment: @NullUserException Ah I understand it now! Thanks!

Comment: @NullUserException Although this triple replacement fails in certain cases: `'"`->`'""` ->`"""` ->`'"`.

Comment: @ChristianKönig Yes, I just realized that. It's an old trick; I just don't remember exactly how it should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good use-case for `string.translate(..)`! In python 2.x:

```
>>> import string
>>> print s.translate(string.maketrans('"\'', "'\""))
'1': ' "me" and "you"'
>>> print s
"1": " 'me' and 'you'"
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) (which I would recommend) you can use a `dict` to manually replace each character:

```
>>> repl={'"': "'", "'":'"'}
>>> oldstr='''"1": " 'me'" and 'you'"'''
>>> newstr="".join([repl[i] if i in repl else i for i in oldstr])
>>> print(oldstr)
"1": " 'me'" and 'you'"
>>> print(newstr)
'1': ' "me"' and "you"'
```